# custom module installation error on odoo 14

Tags: report, odoo

ValueError: ir.actions.report.report_type: required selection fields must define an ondelete policy that implements the proper cleanup of the corresponding records upon module uninstallation. Please use one or more of the following policies: 'set default' (if the field has a default defined), 'cascade', or a single-argument callable where the argument is the recordset containing the specified option.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare like this :

```
report_type = fields.Selection(
        selection_add=[('sale', 'sale')],
        ondelete={'sale': 'cascade'}
    )
```

or you can also add this as per the requirement :

```
ondelete={'sale': 'set default'})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you guys get this issue when database is cached, then try this (otherwise, ignore this solution):

Add dbfilter to odoo.conf:

```
dbfilter = ^your_db_name*
```

Then restart the server and go to /web/database/selector and select your db